# getDay(),getMonth(),getYear()

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport

I have a timestamp textField called $F{Fecha}, and I want to get from it the day,month, and year. I've create 3 variables var1,var2,var3 and in their expressions I've put the following $F{Fecha}.getDay(), $F{Fecha}.getMonth(),$F{Fecha}.getYear(); it gives me in return a value but they're wrong values,ie if my date is 20120118 it returns me day=3, month=0,yearh=112.

How can I do to fix this?
Thanks in advance.

PD. I'm using iReport 4.0.0

Comment: The field `Fecha` should has declaration like this: `<field name="Fecha" class="java.util.Date"/>`. Do you have the same?

Comment: No, I dont. It's Timestamp but I solved it with this:
day: $F{Fecha}.toString().substring(0,10).substring(8,10)
month: $F{Fecha}.toString().substring(0,7).substring(5,7)
year: $F{Fecha}.toString().substring(0,4)

Comment: I think it is not a very good solution.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a way to do it with Java expressions:

Day:
new Integer($F{Fecha}.getDate())

Month:
new Integer($F{Fecha}.getMonth()+1)

Year:
new Integer($F{Fecha}.getYear()+1900)

Comment: Right! The thing is: in jasperReports you must use the whole package reference to a Class

Comment: good answer: how about using `getFullYear()` instead of `getYear()+1900` ?

Answer (score 1):

I'm with Alex: string parsing to pull out date information is a bad idea. For example: run the report using a different Locale, and you'll find the your report breaks in unexpected ways.

Java doesn't have very good date handling built in for this purpose. But you can use Joda-Time or Apache Commons Lang to get a bunch of helpful functions.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, you could do this in the SQL.

MySQL has MONTH(), DAY() and YEAR() functions that would do this.